# Change the text in menu items listed under Site Actions

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, css, branding

I would like to find the best way to change the text of the title and description of some of the items listed under Site Actions.  For example, say I wanted to change "More Options" to "Something Else".

[image]

Maybe JavaScript or CSS.. but what would the actual code be and where do I put it and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to edit the master page. Find the following section and replace the Text and Description properties.

```
    <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Create"
    Text="Something Else"
    Description="Some Description"
    MenuGroupId="200"
    Sequence="240"
    UseShortId="true"
    ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="if (LaunchCreateHandler('All')) { STSNavigate('~site/_layouts/create.aspx') }"
    PermissionsString="ManageLists, ManageSubwebs"
    PermissionMode="Any" />
```

You can also create a CustomAction and add/replace the OOTB Site Action menu. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/02/18/adding-actions-to-site-actions-menu.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try following javascript code:

You can try adding this to your masterpage, or to test it out, use a content editor web part

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   document.getElementById("zz5_MenuItem_Create").setAttribute("text", "More optiontest")
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is there a special place in the master page I should add this code?  I tried some similar code in a txt file linked from a CEWP.  It didn't do anything.  Is there a special way to do it?

Comment: Add it on your master page.